# How to perform evaluation and inference in tensorflow distributed training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, distributed

I understand tensorflow distributed training and I implemented my own script.

What I want to do now is to integrate the possibility of assigning some workers the task of asynchronously evaluate the model.

Let's say we have 6 workers, what I want to do is to use 4 of them to do asynchronous training, one to periodically evaluate the model and another one to periodically make inference on it.

My intuition to achieve this goal is to do the following:

```
....
elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

    if FLAGS.task_index <= (len(cluster_dict["worker"][:-2]) - 1):
         logging.info("Training worker started")
         ...
        with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
                worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
                cluster=cluster,
                ps_tasks=len(cluster_dict["ps"])
            )):
                train_model = Model(
                    mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN
                )
               with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
                    is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                    master=server.target,
                    checkpoint_dir=ckpt_dir,
                    config=config_proto,
                    hooks=hooks
                ) as mon_sess:
                    while not mon_sess.should_stop():
                        res = train_model.train(...)
                        ...

   elif FLAGS.task_index == (len(cluster_dict["worker"][-2]) - 1):
         logging.info("Evaluation worker started")
         ...
         with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
              worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
              cluster=cluster,
              ps_tasks=len(cluster_dict["ps"])
          )):
              eval_model = Model(
                 mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.EVAL
              )
              ...

   elif FLAGS.task_index == (len(cluster_dict["worker"][-1]) - 1):
        logging.info("Inference worker started")
        ...
        with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
               worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
               cluster=cluster,
               ps_tasks=len(cluster_dict["ps"])
            )):
                infer_model = Model(
                    mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.INFER
                )
                ...
```

Now, what about the evaluation and inference sessions?
For training, I can use `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`, but for evaluation and inference I don't see such a cozy solution and the only possibility that I see is to use `tf.Session`.

Regarding the actual evaluation and inference loop, I thought to use a while loop inside which the worker periodically calls `eval_model.eval(...)` or `infer_model.infer(...)`, but this means that the evaluation is performed considering the time and not considering the global_step and the only meaning that I can give to "periodically" is to sleep the thread.

Is it the correct way to asynchronously perform training, evaluation, and inference in a distributed tensorflow setting?